# What's wrong with my code for solving through lists for iteratively to obtain an integer values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am currently trying to write a programme which solves question 5 in project Euler using python, I don't want to look at other solutions before I reach a solution. So far my code is as follows. Here's a link to the question https://projecteuler.net/problem=5

```
a=1000000
n=[int()]
for Num in range(a):
    NumberList=[]
    for n in range(1,20):
       remainder=Num%n

       if remainder==0:
           NumberList.append(Num)


print(min(NumberList))
```

I set a to 2 million as I predicted the solution would be in that range. 
I'm trying to get my code to run through every number from 1 to 1 million which is  divisible by each each number from 1-20.Then my code should each value which is divisible to the NumberList and using the min function I find the lowest integer which is divisible by each value in the range.  I know my code isn't probably the best, I've just started programming so any tips for improvement would be greatly appreciated. My code keeps returning the (range(a)-1) as a solution and I don't know why?

Comment: Please check the `range`'s documentation. `range` will not include the last number.

Comment: `NumberList=[]` is in wrong place. Put it before `for Num`

Comment: (always) add link to Euler question.

Answer (score 0):

min(NumberList) is not the result what you want.The contents in this list is just all the numbers that can be evenly divisible by any of range(1,21)

Comment: and i think this function will spend a very long time

Answer (score 0):

Okay lets see the factors.

1st before I start I would say I really don't understand your intention in the program.

For little convenience, lets take a smaller value. say `a = 200` and `c` in your program is not at all required because you are not using `c`. Hence it is unused here.

Now **firstly**, you have written `NumberList=[]` between the two for loops which means you are re-initializing the `NumberList`. That means all the iterations that you are doing till `a-2` or here `198` is useless. Now why you adopt such kindda algorithm, I don't understand, but if that is your intention then lets move to the second point

**Secondly**, Usually in these case we push the divisor but in your snippet, you are pushing the number instead. Which means instead of writing `NumberList.append(n)` you are writing `NumberList.append(Num)`. Again I don't understand you intention.

Now if I combine first point and second point, what I can see that you will only end up pushing `a-1` every time which means `min(NumberList)` or `max(NumberList)` will have no effect because you will have same number in the array. That that number will be `a-1` always.

**NOTE** *For these kind of questions, read the documentation & debug the code first & then still if you are stuck, you are welcome to ask it here*